# scraping Tweet source labels of a tweet from twitter

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape Tweet source labels of a tweet. But i am not able to get it.

```
import requests as req

url="https://twitter.com/AskPayPal/status/1191653088823635969"
html = req.get(url)
label = html.find('span',class_="css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0")

print(label.text)
```

Output should be : Lithium Tech.

Comment: you tagged beautifulsoup but did not use it `soup.find('span',{'class':'classes'})`

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="https://twitter.com/AskPayPal/status/1191653088823635969"
html = req.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text,'html.parser')
label = soup.find('span',{'class':"css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0"})
print(label.text)
```

this what you are looking for :))

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'. lebel variable is not getting anything.
Output should come Lithium Tech.

Comment: `Label.getText()`